# Does Flash remoting keep the NetConnection Object open?

Tags: flash, coldfusion, remoting

I've built a application that communicates with Coldfusion cfc functions via Remoting. I've noticed that the NetConnection object disconnects after each call, is this expected behaviour? For some reason I was expecting the NetConnection object to stay connected until I closed it myself (I'm making about 1 request per second and had planned for it to stay open).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an HTTP connection, it will not be persistent, but if you're using RTMP, it should be persistent.  Check the connected property.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/NetConnection.html#connected

If you're using RTMP, I'd check to see if the server side code is terminating the connection.